# Symfony Service not exist

Tags: php, symfony, service, controller

I want to use a controller as a service in symfony2. I defined the service in the `test\testBundle\Resources\services.yml` file:

```
parameters:
#    user.example.class: test\testBundle\Example

services:
    test.controller:
        class: test\testBundle\Controller\TestController
```

and call the service in my controller:

```
$this->get('test.controller');
```

but symfony throws the following exception:

> You have requested a non-existent service "test.controller".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have forgotten to import the `services.yml` file from a config file that's already being read, typically app/config/config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: '@MyBundle/Resources/config.yml' }
```

It is a convention to put config files in the `Resources/config` directory inside your bundle, cf. [Importing Configuration with imports](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#service-container-imports-directive) in the Symfony2 docs:

```
imports:
    - { resource: '@MyBundle/Resources/config/config.yml' }
```